# Alter stored procedure or function added extra blank line gap

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012 when I write code for stored procedure and for any function. After that when I want to alter it added extra blank line gap, that's why it seem very unacceptable lenghty..

```
CREATE proc sp_delete_Rte_article_admin_Latest   
(    
@id int    
)    
as    
begin    
if exists (select * from tblRte where Id=@id )    
begin    
    declare @IvanID bigint  

    set @IvanID=(select [IvanArtId] from tblRte where Id=@id )  
    insert into tblRteOnDelete([IvanArtId],[StoryType],[ChannelType],[Filename],
                [Headline],[PublishDate],[Title],[DocScope],[KeyWord],[Byline],[City],
                [State],[StoryDate],[BodyContents],[DownloadedDate],DeleteDate)
    select [IvanArtId],[StoryType],[ChannelType],[Filename],[Headline],[PublishDate],
           [Title],[DocScope],[KeyWord],[Byline],[City],[State],[StoryDate],
           [BodyContents],[DownloadedDate],GETDATE()
      from tblIvanhoeXmlFeeds
     where Id=@id   

    delete from tblRte where Id=@id   
    delete from tblUpdatedRteTopics where IvanArtId=@IvanID  
    delete from tblCheckAllowRte where ArticleID=@IvanID  
    delete from tblAddRteeApprove where ArticleID=@IvanID  

    return 1    
end    
else    
begin    
    return 0    
end    
end
```

What should do for moving this for all time..any setting ?

Comment: Sorry - but I **don't understand** what you're trying to ask - can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: I want to ask actually whenever i open my procedure sql server 2012 add unwanted line gap between lines..so length of procedure is so long..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to know Sqlserver 2012 Configuration Setting or Code Setting so that I could remove 
the black Space Line ,which come after and after whern are going to alter and open again...